# Make a maven artifact from class files only

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

So I have a bunch of class files from an old repo.  I need to make them a dependency in my new project.  I am using the companies Artifactory server as my repo.

I must have something wrong in my metadata.  The jar is installed in artifactory under the correct group and artifact IDs. I can open up the jar in artifactory and the classes are there.

When I do a mvn clean install,  I get class not found errors.

I can see mvn downloading it. I can even go into my local repository,  find the jar and it has the classes in it!

But both eclipse and mvn seem to not find them.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Apart from building a JAR for which you don't have sources? ;-) Serious comment: What do you see if you do `jar -t < myJar.jar`? Does the directory structure you see match the expected package structure of the classes?

Comment: @dnault,  Yes,  the classes are all in their correct place in the jar that is located in my local repo,  so obviously the one I added to artifactory.